how to get endpoints framework mobile api request with protorpc message in django restframe work or django view
my code writen in py2.7 in google app engine and i am using endpoint framework for mobile. now my mobile team has endpoint java create lib from py2.7 and they hit the api with the help of that lib
I am using this code in py2.7 to get the request data
@endpoints.method(UserDetail, UserDetail, http_method='POST', name = 'user.authenticate')
    def authenticate_user(self, request): 
       print(request.user_detail)
       print(request.abc)

now in django i try all APIView
  def post(self,request,*args, **kwargs):

but in request i didnot get data
i try this code also but did not get data
class authenticate_user(View):
  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.body
    header = request.META 

    # data = data.decode('utf-8')
    # post_data = json.loads(data)
    print('----------------')
    print('-request.GET-')
    print(request.GET)
    print('-request.GET-')
    print('-request.FILES-')
    print(request.FILES)
    print('-request.FILES-')
    print('-META-')
    print(header)
    print('-.META-')
    # print('-post_data-')
    # print(post_data)
    # print('-post_data-')
    print('-request.POST-')
    print(request.POST)
    print('-request.POST-')
    print('-request.headers-')
    print(request.headers)
    print('-request.headers-')

    print('----------------')
    return JsonResponse({'success':"hiiii"})

i am geting this. I don't want to change mobile code i want to convert my code in python3 with django
could any one help me. Now endpoint does not sport py3
May be this request get IN RCP
how to get RCp data in django
